# CSS layout problems and responsive issues on only homepage

Tags: css, magento, layout, responsive-design

I am having massive issues sorting out the magento homepage layout for this site

http://creadores.co.uk/

the site it responsive and seems to work well on all pages except the home -

The layout looks ok on a mac but not a pc. Can anyone give me some tips to sorting this out, the issue seems to be something to so with the 3 boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fixed height on this class `.cms-home .pic-main`. The height is `732px`.

Also you have a width on that element. `336px`. I'm not 100% sure if that should be there.
it looks ok on my PC if I remove the width and height.

Comment: it doesn't seem to help when the browser is re-sized for mobile one of the small boxes is floating off to the right - any idea

Answer (score 0):

```
.cms-home .callout-3{
margin-left:355px
}
```

And remove extra div

```
<div class="pic-main">&nbsp;</div>
```

will sure solve issue